# Google search not working properly - logcat included

Tags: google, search

Nexus 6 Android 7.1

I've been having an issue where I will hold the home button down to pull up search, tap on the search bar to bring up the keyboard, and within a few seconds the search bar clears itself and closes the keyboard.

I made a screen recording to show you the issue in action. The first instance I don't type anything, just wait, and it closes itself. The second time I starting typing and it happens again. So basically every time I open search I have to tap the search bar, wait for the keyboard to close, then tap the search bar again, then it works... until i need to search something else.

[Here is the screen recording.](https://streamable.com/e/sz98)

And here is a [logcat](http://pastebin.com/GSsZLqqk) of the crash.

12-03 10:01:36.449   824  1796 seems to be what it spits out when the keyboard actually closes.

Thanks in advance, this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that Nova Launcher is the culprit. Using another launcher fixed the issue for me.